# MsQL query to select column from result

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am working on a messaging app, the database is to communicate with GCM and send a notification every time a new message is sent to a user, in my Messaging table I have 9 fields, below is a graphical presentation:

```
___________________________________________________________________________________________________
|id |to_id | from_id| subject|message|time_sent|user1read|user2read|user1delete|user2delete|gcm_id|
```

the Id is to hold the message id, the to_id is to hold the recipients id, the from_id is to hold the senders id and so on...the gcm_id is to hold the recipients gcm_id so that they are notified that they have received a message, below are three queries I want to implement that will tell which user to notify which in this case is the one receiving, my question is, how can I select the gcm_id column obtained from the first select query?

```
$query = "Select subject ,id, to_id, from_id, user_from, message, time_sent FROM pm
   WHERE id = $id"; 

 $result = $db->query($query);

    $query = "SELECT gcm_id from  
    WHERE 
    CASE
    WHEN to_id = $to_id
    THEN from_id != $to_id
    END";
$result = $db->query($query);

     $query = "SELECT gcm_id from
    WHERE 
    CASE
    WHEN from_id = $to_id
    THEN to_id != $to_id
    END";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's working fine for me.

> select gcm_id from  (Select subject ,id, to_id, from_id, user_from,
>   message, time_sent FROM pm    WHERE id = $id ) as foo;

or

> select gcm_id from  (Select subject ,id, to_id, from_id, user_from,
>   message, time_sent FROM pm    WHERE id = $id );

Comment: I wanted to implement a query that would pull gcm_id based on the three queries but I have already thought of a way out

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking beyond the box, all I needed to do is get the recipients GCM id; in this case the to_id was to be used to get the gcm_id.